# How to embed angular typescript with dynamic height in cross origin

Tags: wordpress, angular, typescript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a Web Application using Angular 6 with dynamic content.

How to embed in cross domain using Iframe and dynamic height without DOM and CORS restriction?

The iframe looks like

```
<iframe src="http://www.myAngularProjects" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Any idea will appreciated, Thanks!